# How can I create a UITextField with ability display both text and emoticon?

Tags: ios, wysiwyg

I need create a UITextField, which can display both text and emoticon. Example, when I type : "abc :)", I will get "abc" text and smile-emoticon. So, how can I do that ?

My idea is create a UIView custom, every text is a UILabel, every emoticon is a UIImageView. But I see it is very complex. I want to find a simpler solution.

Thank for your support.

Comment: @huync- how can you expect help while you haven't accepted answers till now...?

Comment: @AntonioMG, Vivek Sehrawat I don't enough reputation to give vote up for people's answer :(.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I just found accept button today. I don't know about it, I only see vote up button before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [pbrmojilable library](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pbemojilabel)

It may help you.

Comment: If this library helps you. Accept answer

Comment: Thank, I will try and comment result later. But how can I accept your answer. It require 15 reputation to vote up ?